# Destructuring a function call

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, eslint, destructuring

Assuming the following code:

```
this.props.myFunction();
```

EsLint gives out the following error:

```
Must use destructuring props assignment  react/destructuring-assignment
```

While the current code is clear and concise, if I still wanted to destructure the code and make EsLint happy, how could I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md) for this rule say that properties of `props` should be destructured before using them, so just do that:

```
const { myFunction } = this.props;
myFunction();
```

Comment: For some reasons I thought it would be way different for a function compared to an attribute. Thanks!